# Use WooCommerce WC_Order object with wp_schedule_event

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cron-task

I am creating a Cron to trigger cloning an order using `wp_schedule_event`.
It works when I create a function to send email tests every minute. However, when I switch the function to the clone function, nothing happens. What could go wrong?

*PS: This Cron is supposed to run for `weekly`, but for testing purposes, I use `everyminute`*

```
/* create a scheduled event: every minute */
function cron_add_minute( $schedules ) {
    // Adds once every minute to the existing schedules.
    $schedules['everyminute'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __( 'Once Every Minute' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_minute' );

function cronstarter_activation_weekly() {
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'clone_order_weekly' ) ) {  
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everyminute', 'clone_order_weekly' );  
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_action_clone_order_weekly', 'cronstarter_activation_weekly');

// unscheduled event upon plugin deactivation
function cronstarter_deactivate_weekly() {  
    // find out when the last event was scheduled
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('clone_order_weekly');
    // unschedule previous event if any
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'clone_order_weekly');
} 
add_action('woocommerce_order_action_clone_order_stop', 'cronstarter_deactivate_weekly');

function my_repeat_function() { 
    // components for our email
    $recepients = 'xxx@yyy.zzz';
    $subject = 'Hello from your Cron Job';
    $message = 'This is a test mail sent by WordPress automatically as per your schedule.';
    
    // Send email test
    mail($recepients, $subject, $message);
}

/*
* This function works well. I got an email every minute
*/
add_action ('clone_order_weekly', 'my_repeat_function');
```

So with the above code, the cronjob seems to be working just fine.. however when I call the cloning function like so:

```
/**
 * Trigger Clone action from  Order page
 *
 * @param $order
 */
function m_trigger_action_clone_order( $order ) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone($order_id);
}

add_action ('clone_order_weekly', 'm_trigger_action_clone_order', 20, 1);
```

Nothing really happens.. no order is being triggered... I know that `m_trigger_action_clone_order` works because I attached it to a normal clone button and when I click and trigger the function, a new clone is created:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_clone_order', 'm_trigger_action_clone_order', 20, 1 );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass `$order` `(the WC_Order object)` hook argument to the hooked function, when using [`'woocommerce_order_action_' . sanitize_title( $action )` composite hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.3/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-actions.php#L173).

Then you will be able to pass it to [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) and [wp_unschedule_event()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unschedule_event/) functions as an argument. 
Then it should be available in `m_trigger_action_clone_order()` function.

Try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_minute' );
function cron_add_minute( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['everyminute'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __( 'Once Every Minute' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}


add_action('woocommerce_order_action_clone_order_weekly', 'cronstarter_activation_weekly');
function cronstarter_activation_weekly( $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return;
    }

    $args  = array( $order );

    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'clone_order_weekly', $args ) ) {  
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everyminute', 'clone_order_weekly', $args );  
    }
}


add_action('woocommerce_order_action_clone_order_stop', 'cronstarter_deactivate_weekly');
function cronstarter_deactivate_weekly( $order ) {  
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return;
    }

    $args  = array( $order );

    // find out when the last event was scheduled
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('clone_order_weekly', $args );
    // unschedule previous event if any
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'clone_order_weekly', $args );
} 

add_action ('clone_order_weekly', 'trigger_action_clone_order');
function trigger_action_clone_order( $order ) {  
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return;
    }

    // For testing (Send email with the order ID)
    $recipients = 'thename@domain.tld';
    $subject = 'Scheduled Cron Job from Order number #'.$order->get_order_number();
    $message = 'This is a test mail from a scheduled Cron Job on Order number #'.$order->get_order_number();
    wp_mail($recipients, $subject, $message);

    // Your function to be triggered
    mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone( $order->get_id() );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

**For other readers:** We need this to start/stop the cron job from WooCommerce "Order Action" metabox:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_order_actions', 20, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_order_actions( $actions ) {
    $actions['clone_order_weekly'] = __( 'Clone order weekly', 'woocommerce' );
    $actions['clone_order_stop'] = __( 'Clone order stop', 'woocommerce' );

    return $actions;
}
```

Then you will replace `mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone( $order->get_id() );` function with your own…